# How can i send forever data to clients in tornado websocket?

Tags: python, websocket, server, tornado

I'm trying to run a server websocket using tornado, and i want to send messages to clients when i want in a loop not when i want and not onmessage.

This is my code for now :

```
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web


class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
        print 'new connection'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'message received:  %s' % message
        if message == "data":
            self.write_message("message")
            # here i want when i receive data from the client, to continue sending data for it until the connection is closed, and in the some time keep accepting other connections


    def on_close(self):
        print 'connection closed'


    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True


application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/ws', WSHandler),
])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(8888)
    myIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    print '*** Websocket Server Started at %s***' % myIP
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, with a loop that sends a message every second until closed. The trickiest part of this is cancelling the loop when the connection is closed.  This version uses the timeout parameter of `Event.wait`; other alternatives include `gen.with_timeout` and `gen.sleep`.

```
def open(self):
    self.close_event = tornado.locks.Event()
    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(self.loop)

def on_close(self):
    self.close_event.set()

@gen.coroutine
def loop(self):
    while True:
        if (yield self.close_event.wait(1.0)):
            # yield event.wait returns true if the event has
            # been set, or false if the timeout has been reached.
            return
        self.write_message("abc")
```

Comment: Hello Ben, thank you for the solution, but the problem is that i don't want messages to be sent in specific time, i want to keep sending messages when i have ready data to send, for example :  i'm getting real time data and i want just when i got new data send it, in the some time i keep listening to new clients.

Comment: I tested a solution, but i don't know if it is a professional one:
I built a "special clients" in python that will be responsible for data gathering, and it will keep sendenig it the server, the data will include a passphrase to distunct his message from other clients messages, and the server will send the data received from it to all clients.